# How do I install fsl and Afni compatible with Ubuntu 22.04 Lts on my surface pro Windows 11?

Tags: system-installation, windows, compatibility

I have been trying to download fsl, (https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/), and/ or afni,(https://www.opensourceimaging.org/project/afni/), for Neuro image analysis; as I have already installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my surface pro 7 Windows 11

Comment: That's great! Did you encounter some kind of problem? Or did you have a question? Links to the software and to the instructions you followed would be very helpful.

Comment: It is definitely not working I run into errors and failure to install. 
Fsl instructions on this website : https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/Windows

Comment: And this is the latest instructions to install afni: https://afni.nimh.nih.gov/pub/dist/doc/htmldoc/background_install/install_instructs/steps_linux_ubuntu20.html

Comment: "run into errors" is too vague to offer useful advice. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1413557/edit) to show us complete error output.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst trying to install FSL on Ubuntu 22.04 I also had some issues.

When running the `fslinstaller.py` script there were no errors but it seemed the environment variables hadn't been set.

FSL worked fine after I had set them manually using (from https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/ShellSetup):

```bash
# FSL Setup
FSLDIR=/usr/local/fsl
PATH=${FSLDIR}/share/fsl/bin:${PATH}
export FSLDIR PATH
. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
```

(May have to modify FSLDIR if FSL has been installed in a different location to the default.)